# WordPress/Gutenberg - Limitation of characters

Tags: javascript, wordpress, jsx, wordpress-gutenberg

I created a Gutenberg's block and I would like to limit the number of characters in the field.

For the moment all works fine. I can display the numbers of characters in real time in the counter.
But I use RichText component. This component allows to format text (bold, italic...). For this reason I must count the characters without html tags.

I use `whithoutTags` function to count the number of characters without html tags. This function works fine too.

How to stop text input after characters limit exceeded in my field ?

[image]

edit.js (back office) :

```
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n'
import { useBlockProps, RichText } from '@wordpress/block-editor'
import { useState } from '@wordpress/element';

import './editor.scss'

export default function Edit(props) {
    const blockProps = useBlockProps();
    const [charsCount, setMsg] = useState(0);

    const onChangeContent = content => {
        props.setAttributes( { content: content } )
    }

    // Limitation of characters
    const charsLimit = 10;

    const whithoutTags = str => {
        let tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
        tmp.innerHTML = str;
        return tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText || "";
    }

    let completeString = whithoutTags(props.attributes.content);

    if (charsCount > charsLimit) {
        let stringRender = completeString.slice(0, charsLimit);
    }

    return (
        <div { ...blockProps }>
            <div className="gut-tag-field">
                <label className="gut-tag-label">{ __( 'Titre', 'ccn-gut' ) }</label>
                <RichText
                    title="Title"
                    tagName="div"
                    placeholder={ __( 'Your title...', 'ccn-gut' ) }
                    value={ props.attributes.content }
                    className="gut-tag-input"
                    onChange={ onChangeContent }
                    allowedFormats={ [ 'core/italic' ] }
                    onKeyUp={() => setMsg(completeString.length)}
                />
                <p className="gut-tag-counter">{ charsCount } { __( 'character(s)', 'ccn-gut' ) } / { charsLimit }</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `onChangeContent()` function you can check if the new value is greater than the limit, and if so, just not set a new value for the `content` attribute.

Something like:

```js
if (content.length <= charsLimit) {
    props.setAttributes( { content: content } )
}
```

Comment: Oh thank you for your help. 2 days I try to find a solution lol. When I try your condition the counter stop at 10 characters and I can continue to type into the field. It's really strange. When I delete all into `onChangeContent()`I Can continue to type text. It's a problem with "value" ?

Comment: Ah, I see. This may be a limitation on the `RichText` component. The above code does work with a `TextControl` component.

Comment: Oh no :-( I undestand. And it's possible to add a toolbar with bold/italic... with a `TextControl` ? Or it's possible to stop typing text in other way with `RichText`component ?

Comment: No, it isn't possible to add formatting controls to a `TextControl`. You could try wrapping your `RichText` component in a [`<Disabled>`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/components/disabled/) component and toggling based on character count. Haven't tested this though.

Comment: I wrapped `RichText` with `<disabled>` component unfortunately it does not work. It works with an input field

Comment: It's not possible to disable `onKeyDown` when 10 characters are reached?  Or disable keyboard? Something like `preventDefault`in jsx ?